# How to calculate decimal(x, y) max value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I know the maximum value of `decimal` type?

For example:

```
decimal(5, 2)
```

Can you please explain the mechanism of `decimal` type?

Comment: @JamesZ thanks. What if I try to put `999.999`?

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: You should get a data truncation error. Wouldn't it be easier to test it than ask here?

Comment: @JamesZ I tried and it's working. My new question is why.

Comment: That wasn't your question at all

Comment: @Lamak my new question.. OK?

Comment: Then you should go read the [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) . `By default, SQL Server uses rounding when converting a number to a decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale`

Comment: @Lamak Thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function in order to get the maximum value in a column

```
SELECT MAX(myColumn) AS MyColumnMax
FROM myTable
```

If you want to know the maximum value for each customer for instance, you can group by this customer

```
SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderAmount) AS MaxOrderAmount
FROM CustomerOrders
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

You can find other [aggregate functions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

---

If, by contrast, you are interested in range of a decimal type, then consider, that you are declaring the total number of digits and decimals. Therefore the maximum number is reached, when all these digits are `9`.

So for `decimal(5,2)` it would be `999.99`. **5** is the total number of decimals  to the left and to the right of the decimal point. **2** is the number of decimals to the right of the decimal point.

The maximum possible range for decimals is -10^38 + 1 through 10^38 - 1.

Comment: My question is about the possible maximum value of decimal.

Comment: You said decimal column. But you are referring to the decimal type as such, which can also be used for variables and parameters in TSQL.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is cover all the information for my question.

Answer (score 23):

The maximum **possible** value can be calculated using the following maths:

```
(10 ^ (x-y)) - (10 ^ -y)
```

So in your initial example

```
(10 ^ (5-2)) - (10 ^ -2) = 1000 - 0.01 = 999.99
```

I'm adding this answer as my google results took me here when trying to remind myself how to calculate the SQL friendly upper bounds of a C# decimal going into an SQL `(28,10)` decimal field.

`999999999999999999.9999999999` by the way.

Comment: I think it can be helpful to point out that **X** is called **precision** here, which stands for the total ammount of numbers/digits, including decimals, and **Y scale**, standing for the total ammount of *only* decimals. So - (5,2) ->P.E. 999.99

Comment: Great formula! If anyone need this in javascript code (i.e. to provide max limit on input fields) I will recommend to build up a string with the number instead of calculating mathematically, because of floating point accuracy issues in javascript:
`var maxValue = (new Array(precision - scale + 1).join('9') + '.' +  new Array(scale + 1).join('9'));`